# Xcode - Debug View Hierarchy

Tags: swift, xcode, debugging, uikit, mapkit

I'm trying to debug my app's view hierarchy and a little purple square appeared on the left pane of Xcode's window (see screenshot).

Any idea what that issue could be?

[image: Xcode - Debug View Hierarchy]

Comment: Click on the issues navigator and it will show you the runtime issues. Most likely it’s a constraint warning.

Comment: I think you are doing something with map view in background queue. So check and place that code in main queue.

Comment: I looked at the issue navigator and no runtime issues. I also checked how the map view is loaded - it happens in the main queue. What I'm trying to do here is to show a map view inside a table view cell.

Answer (score 16):

Alright! I found where this issue comes from… It's a constraint issue!!!

[image]